# Fetch Microsoft Security Alerts for a specific user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-security

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph Security API to fetch security alerts for a specific user. It looks like I should be using the `filter` parameter. But I can't figure out the property to search on. I can't find the common schema defined anywhere.
Only finding generic documentation like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter
Is there a schema that I can reference?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a name of the analyst the alert is assigned to for triage, investigation, or remediation then you can use `assignedTo` property.

Filter by analyst name

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/alerts?$filter=assignedTo eq '{analyst_name}'
```

If you want to get security-related stateful information generated by the provider about the user accounts related to alerts then you can use `userStates` property.

Filter by user related to the alerts

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/alerts?$filter=userStates/any(d:d/userPrincipalName eq '{user_mail}')
```

Resources:

[Alert resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/alert?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Do you know if there are similar OData filters that can be used on the alert evidence for the alerts_v2 endpoint to accomplish the same thing?